# Is There a German Equivalent For "Shoot the Messenger?"

Tags: proverb

Is there a German equivalent for "shoot the messenger" (kill the bearer, but not the originator, of bad news)?

Comment: I only found this link http://www.forum-3dcenter.org/vbulletin/archive/index.php/t-255505.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not literally equivalent, but this phrase is commonly used in German:

> nicht den Überbringer der schlechten Nachrichten (oder Botschaften) bestrafen.

which means: *Don't punish the bearers of bad news.*

---

*Related:* the German for the person who's always blamed even if he or she is innocent: *Prügelknabe* or *Sündenbock* (scapegoat).

Comment: ... or *Sündenbock*.

Comment: @Pekka danke! ♣ ← *15 characters minimum filling symbol*

Comment: "Not literally equivalent." But quite good enough.

Comment: Der bestrafte Bote ist aber nur ein Spezialfall des Sündenbocks - daher ist Sündenbock unpassend.

Answer (score 1):

I think "no" is not a sufficient answer, is it?
I don't think there is one, at least not a commonly used one. The dictionaries in which I've found it seem to only explain the meaning.

[Wikipedia: Shooting the Messenger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shooting_the_messenger) says that its origin is from a play by Shakespeare. So it could be a proverb without german equivalent.

Comment: The "principle" of killing the messenger is ancient though: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bote#Der_.C3.9Cberbringer_der_schlechten_Nachricht

Answer (score 1):

Auch wenn die richtige Antwort schon vorliegt: "den Boten bestrafen" (to punish the messenger) ist vielleicht noch etwas kompakter, und Alliterationen sind doch immer was schönes :-)